# A group may have two distinct characteristic Sylow-$p$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, characteristic-subgroups

There is a statement:

> A group may have two distinct characteristic Sylow-$p$-subgroups.

I think it is not necessarily true because if there is unique Sylow-$p$-subgroups, it is characteristic; if the group is characteristic, it is unique Sylow-$p$-subgroup.

Can anyone give some details about this?

Comment: If there is just one $p$-Sylow subgroup then it is clearly characteristic. If there are at least $2$ such subgroups then they are conjugate to each other, and so they are not even normal in $G$.

Comment: @Mark Yeah Actually I thought about this so that implies the statement is false. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is false.

Comment: Could they be refering to Sylow subgroups corresponding to different primes? The cyclic group os order 6 has a characteristisc 2-Sylow and a characteristic 3-Sylow. Please provide source and complete context.

Answer (score 1):

The Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ are all conjugate. So if there are > 1 such subgroups, conjugation by some element of $G$ sends one Sylow p-subgroup to another. Conjugation by a fixed element of $G$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Why did you mention automorphism?

Comment: What is the definition of a characteristic subgroup?

Answer (score 1):

The question could also be interpreted differently: it is not clear if we are talking about the *same* prime $p$ - of a nilpotent group with $|G|$ having more than one prime divisor, all its different Sylow subgroups are characteristic.